# Plot the cluster member in r

Tags: r, plot, time-series, data-mining, hierarchical-clustering

I use DTW package in R. 
and I finally finished hierarchical clustering.
but I wanna plot time-series cluster separately like below picture.

[image]

```
sc <- read.table("D:/handling data/confirm.csv", header=T, sep="," )
rownames(sc) <- sc$STDR_YM_CD
sc$STDR_YM_CD <- NULL
col_n <- colnames(sc)

hc <- hclust(dist(sc), method="average")
plot(hc,  main="")
```

How can I do it??
My data in http://blogattach.naver.com/e772fb415a6c6ddafd1370417f96e494346a9725/20170207_141_blogfile/khm2963_1486442387926_THgZRt_csv/confirm.csv?type=attachment

Comment: How many clusters do you want in the data? Also could you please put your data here? The link is in Chinese which I don't understand.

Comment: Oh I don't know how can I put the data in this post.
I will indicate how can people get the data
or would you give me your email address??

Comment: your time series is along the columns but you are clustering the rows. Don't you need to cluster the columns?

Comment: oh yes I need cluster the columns.
when I check the result, I feel something weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
sc <- read.table("confirm.csv", header=T, sep="," )
rownames(sc) <- sc$STDR_YM_CD 
sc$STDR_YM_CD <- NULL
col_n <- colnames(sc)

sc <- t(sc) # make sure your rows represent the time series data
id <- rownames(sc)
head(sc)

hc <- hclust(dist(sc), method="average")
plot(hc,  main="")

n <- 20
sc <- cbind.data.frame(id=id, sc, cluster=cutree(hc, k = n))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
sc %>% gather(variable, value, -id, -cluster) %>%
ggplot(aes(variable, value, group=id, color=id)) + geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~cluster, scales = 'free') + guides(color=FALSE) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: really Thanks~ I got graph!!! You are best women?? or guy?? ~~
I have a another question. I changed the second line code `rownames(sc) <- id`  to   `rownames(sc) <- sc$STDR_YM`_CD .
Is it ok?? when I use first code, I got erorr message

Comment: Thanks~~ I hope many people see this answer in order to sharing of this great knowledge

Comment: how does the data look can you head the data ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cutree` to cluster the data points and use `facet_wrap` (from package `ggplot2`) on clusters to plot them. Since I couldn't get your data, I have an example from publicly available data.

```
narrest <- USArrests

# Clustering
hc <- hclust(dist(narrest), "ave")
plot(hc)

# Cut the tree to required number of clusters, here 3
narrest$clusters <- cutree(hc, k = 3)

# use facet_wrap from ggplot to one variable Murder 
d <- ggplot(narrest, aes(y=Murder, x=1:nrow(narrest))) + geom_line()
d + facet_wrap(~ clusters)
print(d)
```

Comment: Hi~ really thanks~ but I change my link for file.
So could you show me the demonstration??
I think My data is something wrong.. HAHA
I don't know where y values is.