# hclust and ggplot r

Tags: r, ggplot2, hclust

I have a file with values as seen below

```
gene_name s1    s2  s3  s4  s5
gene1  0.5004357 -0.9613324  1.4624021 -0.8051191 -0.1963863
gene2  1.1662839 -0.3210387 -0.3653730 -1.3095341  0.8296619
gene3  1.0511340 -0.7007560 -0.3025992  1.0511340 -1.0989128
gene4 -0.2422484 -0.4203723  0.4651577 -1.2295635  1.4270265
gene5 -1.3491928 -0.6743735  0.1860456  0.9507387  0.8867820
gene6 -0.9254673  0.1860328 -1.0089603  0.3438866  1.4045082
dim(df)
[1] 21752     5
```

What i am trying to achieve is use hclust and dist method to see for trends in the data, I am trying to basically do something that is shown in the question[here from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081879/plot-the-cluster-member-in-r)
p.s answer by sandipan dey

I am not able to understand as there is no data shown in the question, what i would like to plot is

1. x: xaxis my sample names (s1,s2,s3,s4,s5)
2. y axis the zscore and
3. each line representing each genename
4. facet_wrap for each cluster, where i could see which cluster would give a good clear clustering or separation of sample

### EDIT

Based on answer
[image]

my version of code

```
d_final <- cbind.data.frame(expr, cluster=cutree(hc, k = n))
d_final %>% 
  gather(key, value, -geneID, -cluster) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=key, y=value, color=factor(cluster), group=geneID)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_path() +
  facet_wrap(~cluster) #changed it to wrap
```

when i try this

```
d <- dist(expr[,-1] , method = "euclidean")
hc <- hclust(dist(d), method = "average")
```

on a mac with 16gb ram R studio freezes

Comment: Did you look at the dendextend R package?

Comment: no sir, not aware of that package, has some one used it to generate such plots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
hc <- hclust(dist(d[,-1]))
plot(hc)
# try three clusters for instance: 
n <- 3
d_final <- cbind.data.frame(d, cluster=cutree(hc, k = n))
d_final %>% 
  gather(key, value, -gene_name, -cluster) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=key, y=value, color=factor(cluster), group=gene_name)) + 
     geom_point() + geom_path() +
     coord_flip() +
     facet_grid(~gene_name)
```

[image]

```
 # or change to
    facet_grid(~cluster)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, let me try it on my actual data will post the output in few minutes.

Comment: It works perfectly! I have updated the comments, one last question is there a way I can get which gene_symbols belong to which cluster? for eg if i need to know which gene_symbols were involved in cluster 25 is it possible ?

Comment: try to change the color to `color=geneID`. But I guess the plots are really noisy then. Perhaps a table illustrate this information better? Try `aggregate(d_final$gene_name, list(d_final$cluster), paste, collapse=",")`

Comment: Which line should i integrate this to?

Comment: instead of `color=factor(cluster)`